# Changing the image of a button in XAML using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

i recently started learning windows phone 8.1 Development using C#. i have no prior experience to C# or XAML till last week.

I'm trying to change the image in a button as seen below (XAML)

```
<Button x:Name="playButton"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Click="Button_Click">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="controlImg" Source="/Assets/Media-Play.png" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" Play" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

The initial Image is a 'play' icon and a text which says play. This works and renders properly. But i want to change that image when the button is clicked to a 'pause' icon and the text which says Pause.

Here is my C# code so far

```
    private mediaState medState = mediaState.Stopped;

    public BitmapImage iconStop = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media-Stop.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    public BitmapImage iconPause = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media-Pause.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    public BitmapImage iconPlay = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media-Play.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        switch (medState)
        {
            case mediaState.Playing:
                medState = mediaState.Paused;
                mediaE.Pause();
                playButton.Content = " Play";
                controlImg.Source = this.iconPlay;
                break;

            case mediaState.Paused:
                medState = mediaState.Playing;
                mediaE.Play();
                playButton.Content = " Pause";
                controlImg.Source = this.iconPause;
                break;

            case mediaState.Stopped:                    
                medState = mediaState.Playing;
                mediaE.Play();
                playButton.Content = " Pause";
                controlImg.Source = this.iconPause;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    public enum mediaState
    {
        Playing,
        Paused,
        Stopped
    }
```

`mediaE` is the mediaElement object.
Currently when you click the button the text changes but the image in the button doesn't disappears

WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR:

i checked the MSDN article for using `BitmapImage` and some other questions here and the usually say something like this

```
// Create source
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Water Lilies.jpg");
```

But my visual studio doesn't even recognise `BitmapImage.BeginInit()` as a valid function.

i also checked this question: [BitmapImage missing BeginInit() and EndInit() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893837/bitmapimage-missing-begininit-and-endinit-function) Where the answer said that the Class wasn't implemented the same way for windows phone. Checking the windows phone documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of the class didn't show any clear way of achieving what i wanted.

NOTE: i am developing for windows phone 8.1. please any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @taLhaKhan i tried that it threw an exception.

Comment: try this BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/Media-Stop.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

Comment: @loop tried it. it threw an argument exception too: The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri.

Comment: try this: public BitmapImage iconPlay = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Media-Play.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

Comment: Have you tried: new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/Media-Play.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

Comment: @igrali i have tried them both. both throw an exception

Comment: @RaymondAtivie on the yop you said you are developing for Windows pho/ne 8.1 and on bottom you said Windows 8.1 can you make it clear ? ----- Can you add what exceptions are you getting so that we can get more idea about your problem ? Just make it very clear which template you choose for your app :)

Comment: @loop Yes i am developing for windows phone 8.1. 
Exception of type `System.ArgumentException` Additional information: `The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri`. i choose a blank windows phone 8.1 project to begin

Comment: Check this one controlImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(controlImg.BaseUri, "Assets/Media-Play.png")); if it works let me know :)

Comment: @loop tried it... still didnt work :(

Comment: I don't why is this happening. It is working for me. I have selected a   Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight  form VS 13. and change the images property to `Content` . Answerer code just work fine.

Comment: I am not using `Blank App(Windows phone silverlight)` template. i am using the `Blank App(Windows Phone)`. they are two different templates

Comment: @RaymondAtivie just place your Image Control out button(say above Button) you will see your result. Actually their something wrong how you put your stackpanel in Button. You should add this content to ContentTemplate.

Comment: @RaymondAtivie check the solution. Let me know if you have problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are just behaving weird in Windows phone runtime apps may be it is because we haven't explored it too much. But will do it.

I have tried things using Binding too that is also showing some issues in updating, so what i am proposing is not a good solution but a working one. I will update here a good solution latter when i made that work.

**Solution** :-

Update your xaml as it is not the right way you should use ContentTemplate for altering display for any control. and check difference between control and content template.

**Xaml :-**

```
    <Button x:Name="PlayButton" Grid.Row="1"
                Click="PlayButton_OnClick" >
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="ControlImg" 
                   Stretch="Fill" Width="100"
                   />
                    <TextBlock Text=" Play" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
```

Change your **Button Click event** by adding some code :-

```
 private async void PlayButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        // For TextBlock change the children collection index to 1
        var img = (Image)(btn.ContentTemplateRoot as StackPanel).Children[0];

        switch (medState)
        {
            case mediaState.Playing:
                medState = mediaState.Paused;
             //   mediaE.Pause();
                PlayButton.Content = " Play";
                img.Source = this.iconPlay;
                break;

            case mediaState.Paused:
                medState = mediaState.Stopped;
               // mediaE.Play();
                PlayButton.Content = " Pause";
                img.Source = this.iconPause;
                break;

            case mediaState.Stopped:
                medState = mediaState.Playing;
               // mediaE.Play();
                PlayButton.Content = " Stop";
                img.Source = this.iconStop;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**For Windows phone SilverLight I haven't remove this info as it is useful.**

`Here I used the Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight app template`

You can check the ImageFailed EventHandler `ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e` parameter then you will see "**AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR**" that is related to `cross-scheme security` problem in `Silverlight`. 
you can google `AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR` then you will get lot's of stuff related to it.

**Solution Code** :-

`Change images`

```
public BitmapImage iconStop = new BitmapImage();
public BitmapImage iconPause = new BitmapImage();
public BitmapImage iconPlay = new BitmapImage();

private void PlayButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (medState)
    {
        case mediaState.Playing:
            medState = mediaState.Paused;
            //  mediaE.Pause();
            playButton.Content = " Play";

            var sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/download(1).jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            iconStop.SetSource(sri.Stream);
            ControlImg.Source = iconStop;
            break;

        case mediaState.Paused:
            medState = mediaState.Stopped;
            //  mediaE.Play();
            playButton.Content = " Pause";
            var sri1 = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/download(2).jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            iconPlay.SetSource(sri1.Stream);
            ControlImg.Source = iconPlay;
            break;

        case mediaState.Stopped:
            medState = mediaState.Playing;
            // mediaE.Play();
            playButton.Content = " stopped";
            var sri2 = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/download(1).jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            iconStop.SetSource(sri2.Stream);
            ControlImg.Source = iconStop;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: `Application.GetResourceStream()` doesnt exist in my namespace. what is the full definition? `Windows.UI.XAML.Application`? NB: I am not using `silverlight`

Comment: you are making windows phone 8.1 application using VS 2013 right.

Comment: Yes i am developing for windows Phone 8.1 using VS 2013